# Extended methods to a DLL

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, vb.net-2010

I created a couple of extended methods in a VB.NET module. I put them inside a Class, built it and got the DLL. 
From another program I made a reference to that DLL and imported it using `Imports` as well.
The extended methods appear in IntelliSense and it works but a warning appears in the Error console saying,

**Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "nK0deExtendedMethods". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk.**

Does anyone know why this error occurs even though I have referenced the DLL??

This is the Class where I've put my module with the extended method.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Drawing

Namespace nK0deExtendedMethods

    Public Module ExtMethods

        <Extension()>
        Public Function Merge(ByVal img1 As Image, ByVal img2 As Image) As Image

            Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Math.Max(img1.Width, img2.Width), img1.Height + img2.Height)
            Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)

            g.DrawImage(img1, 0, 0, img1.Width, img1.Height)
            g.DrawImage(img2, 0, img1.Height, img2.Width, img2.Width)
            g.Dispose()

            Return bmp

        End Function

    'Public Class NewImageMethods

    'End Class

End Namespace
```

And I'm having another doubt. In the `Imports` statement, I have to mention the DLL's name along with the `Namespace` name. Like this,

```
Imports ExtendedMethods.nK0deExtendedMethods
```

Normally you only have to import the Namespace's name, right? why that is happening?

Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: Did you tried to clean and rebuild your solution ?

Comment: @AmenAyach yes, but nothing changed.

Comment: In those bad situations, I use Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/hh205949) to check where the loading of the dll fails. Good luck.

Comment: I sorted it out, guys. I created a new class, removed the class name and the `Namespace`, inserted the module and build it again. Solved both issues. Thanks for your responses. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a new `Class`, removed the `Namespace` and build it. That worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The VB 'Module' type is pretty special.

You can use:

```
Imports ExtendedMethods
```

But then you have to reference code like this:

```
nK0deExtendedMethods.ExtMethods.Merge(Nothing, Nothing)
```

Comment: I sorted it out. I created a new class, removed the class name and the `Namespace` and inserted the module. Solved both issues. Thanks for your response. Appreciate it :)